# Make editing information in User Panel

Tags: node.js

How do I write a system for the user to enter or edit information to make the final purchase? Like all other shopping websites?
I'm using **nodejs** to do this

Comment: Thank you for telling us, you are using node js. Please read the document, how to ask question first.

Comment: what you have written till now?

Comment: All store websites have user panel. Inside the User Panel, there is a user editing information to allow the user to submit their address so that the product can be delivered to that address.
Now how do I register user information?
What system should I use so that the user can edit their information?